# Fitting of a sum of vectors $Y \alpha = X \beta + \epsilon$

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, linear-algebra

**Related question / Motivation**

This question is related to the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549774). But the difference in this question is that the weights can be different on both sides of the equation.

---

**This question**

This question is an extension of linear regression where we find coefficients $\beta$ relating to the model

$$y = X \beta  + \epsilon = \hat{y} + \epsilon$$

The solution that minimizes $\epsilon$ is also maximizing the correlation between $y$ and $\hat{y}$.

What if $y$ is now containing some flexibility as well and we have a model like

$$ Y \alpha = X \beta  + \epsilon$$

To minimize the $\epsilon$ the trivial answer is $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being equal to $0$ but say that we exclude this option? Ie. we could add the restriction that $\sum \alpha_i  = 1$

**Find coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that we maximize the correlation between $Y \alpha $ and $X\beta $.**

We can assume that the columns in $X$ and $Y$ have zero mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the correlation between $Y \alpha $ and $X \beta$ is maximized then the $\beta$ are such that it is the OLS solution of $\alpha Y$ (where we either translate the columns in $X$ such that the column means are zero, or we add an intercept to the OLS regression).

So we have $$X \beta = X(X^T X)^{-1}X^TY \alpha = Y_{\parallel} \alpha$$

the difference is

$$X \beta  - Y \alpha = (X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T-I)Y \alpha = Y_{\perp} \alpha$$

The image below illustrates this in 3 dimensions.
[image: illustration]

The possible solutions $Y\alpha$ and $X\beta$ are in a surface spanned by the vectors $Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_n$ and $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$. For a given $\alpha$ the solution of $\beta$ that minimizes the correlation is the OLS solution, ie. the perpendicular projection of $Y\alpha$ onto the surface spanned by $X$.

<sup>In this example with 3D coordinates we see that the planes intersect and $\alpha$ can be changed such that the vector $Y\alpha$ is entirely in the plane spanned by $X$. And the correlation can be made equal to 1. But in more dimensions, the hyper-surfaces might not need to intersect (except in the point zero where the planes always intersect).</sup>

---

#### Solution with optimization using a Lagrangian function

Maximizing the correlation between $X \beta $ and $Y \alpha$ is like minimizing the ratio of the length of the vectors $Y_{\perp} \alpha$ and $Y_{\parallel} \alpha$ or $Y \alpha$. The correlation is larger for a smaller remainder $Y_{\perp} \alpha$ while keeping the projection $Y_{\parallel}\alpha$ or total vector $Y \alpha$ the same size.

We can solve this by minimizing the Lagrangian

$$L(\alpha, \lambda) = \alpha^T \, M_{\perp} \, \alpha + \lambda(\alpha^T \, M \, \alpha - 1)$$

where $M_{\perp} = Y_{\perp}^TY_{\perp}$ and $M = Y^TY$

whose gradient must be zero leading to the equations

$$ \begin{array}{}
(M_{\perp}+\lambda M) \alpha &=& 0 \\
 \alpha^T\,M \, \alpha  &=& 1
\end{array}$$

To solve the first equation,  we are looking for a constant $\lambda$ and vector $\alpha$ such that

$$M_{\perp}\alpha = -\lambda M \alpha $$

or

$$(M^{-1}M_{\perp}) \alpha = -\lambda \alpha $$

Which makes the $-\lambda$ and $\alpha$ the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $(M^{-1}M_{\perp})$.

The solution with the maximum correlation will be related with the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_v = -\lambda$. This is because we can compute the correlation as

$$\rho = \sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha^T \, M_{\perp} \, \alpha }{\alpha^T \, M \, \alpha }} = \sqrt{1-\frac{\alpha^T \, \lambda_v M \, \alpha }{\alpha^T \, M \, \alpha }} = \sqrt{1-\lambda_v} $$

So an algorithm to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is to compute the eigenvectors of that matrix and select the one with the smallest absolute value of the eigenvalue.

#### Code example

```r
library(MASS)
set.seed(1)
### create X and Y
X = t(mvrnorm(3,mu = rep(0,10), Sigma = diag(10) ))
Y = t(mvrnorm(3,mu = rep(0,10), Sigma = diag(10) ))

### subtract the means (without loss of generality)
X = X - rep(1,10) %*% t(colMeans(X))
Y = Y - rep(1,10) %*% t(colMeans(Y))

### compute matrices
P = X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)  ### projection matrix
Ypar = P %*% Y                        ### Y projected on X 
Yperp = Y-Ypar                        ### residual of projection
M = t(Y) %*% Y               ### quadratic form to compute square length
Mperp = t(Yperp) %*% Yperp


### solve with eigenvectors
eV = eigen(solve(t(M)) %*% Mperp)$vectors


### compute Xbeta and Yalpha 
### when putting alpha equal to the last eigenvector
### the last eigenvalue is the one with the lowest eigenvalue
alpha = alpha = eV[,length(eV[1,])]
yfit = Y %*% alpha
xfit = P %*% yfit
corrV = cor(yfit,xfit)


### optimization of correlation
f<-function(p){
  a1 = p[1:3]
  a2 = p[4:6]
  rho = cor((Y %*% a1),(X  %*% a2))
  d = abs(sum(a1^2)-1)^2
  return(-rho+d)
}

a = rep(1,6)
### optimize correlation
mod <- optim(a,f, method = "BFGS",control = list(maxit=1*10^5,trace=1,reltol=10^-16))
mod

### check results of models 
yh = Y %*% mod$par[1:3]
xh = X %*% mod$par[4:6]

### correlation from optimization
### 0.69886626
cor(yh,xh)

### correlation from eigenvectors 
### 0.6988626 (it's the same)
max(corrV)
```

#### Intuition

The correlation in terms of the vector $\alpha$ is the ratio of the length of the vectors

$$\rho = \frac{\Vert Y_{\parallel} \alpha \Vert}{\Vert Y \alpha \Vert} = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^T \, M_{\parallel} \, \alpha}{\alpha^T \, M \, \alpha}} =\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^T \, M^{-1} M_{\parallel}  \alpha}{\alpha^T\alpha}}$$

If we restrict the $\alpha$ to be of a specific size then the alpha that maximizes this product $\alpha^T \, M^{-1} M_{\parallel}  \, \alpha$ is directed along the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.